# Understanding「1千万円以上は下らない代物」

Tags: grammar, meaning

From One Piece ch. 97,

[image]

I am not sure how should I understand「1千万ベリー以上は下らない代物」. I know it means something like "item that cannot be less than 10 million berries." The word 下らない throws me off. I initially interpreted 1千万ベリー以上は下らない as "cannot drop (price) more than 10 million berries" which is wrong. How 1千万ベリー以上は下らない is understood literally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Xはくだらない is an idiomatic usage meaning *not being less than X*, where X is a price. (cf. [下る](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E4%B8%8B%E3%82%8B_%28%E3%81%8F%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8B%29/#jn-61845) #8.)

Literally 下る here is a transitive verb meaning 'going below *obj.*'  So it means *(the value) does not go below 一千万ベリー*.

---

以上 in 一千万ベリー以上 is redundant and should be 一千万ベリーはくだらない.